# I need to create several columns from several rows

Tags: mysql, case

I have a MYSQL table I use from another plugin. The table has two fields called element_value and element_label.

element_value contains the name, address, city, state and zip of 2500 people for which I want to create a report.  But, I want to take each row and create it's own column.

For example, the table looks like this:

```
**element_value**
John Smith
100 Elm Street
Columbus
Ohio
13579
```

element_label is used as an index.  element_label 1 relates to the name, 2 the address, 3 the city, etc.

I want to be able to diplay the data in columns:

```
Name       Address        City       State       Zip
John Smith 100 Elm Street Columbus   Ohio        13579
```

Can anyone think of how to use a MYSQL statement to do this?

Comment: How do you link a name to an address?

Answer (score 0):

This type of transformation from rows to columns is called a *pivot*. MySQL does not have an pivot function but this can be replicated using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

You can use the following:

```
select
  max(case when element_label = 'Name' then element_value end) Name,
  max(case when element_label = 'Address' then element_value end) Address,
  max(case when element_label = 'State' then element_value end) State,
  max(case when element_label = 'City' then element_value end) City,
  max(case when element_label = 'Zip' then element_value end) Zip
from yt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/700749/1).

If you had an unknown number of values that you want to convert to columns, then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic sql:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN element_label = ''',
      element_label,
      ''' THEN element_value else null END) AS `',
      element_label, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yt;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
            from yt
            ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/700749/3).  Both queries give the result:

```
|       NAME |        ADDRESS |     CITY | STATE |   ZIP |
----------------------------------------------------------
| John Smith | 100 Elm Street | Columbus |  Ohio | 13579 |
```

Typically, you will have a column that you will group by as well.  For example, if you have a record_id column, then you will add a `GROUP BY record_id`, so you will return more than one row of results.